# Python - after adding some items the list is still empty problem

Tags: python, list

I'm new to programming, so please explain me one thing
I have got a character. He has got a inventory. The inventory is a list

```
class Steve:
    def __init__(self):
        self.inv = []
```

I'm trying to do a picking-up mechanic. If there wasn't such a item before, I will add it to the inventory. But if there already was the "new item", i want there to be an amount counter right in the list like:

```
    def pickUp(self, item):
        amount = 0
        for i in self.inv:
            if i == item:
                amount += 1
                self.inv[i] == self.inv[i] + amount
            else:
                self.inv.append(item)
```

But if I try it:

```
s = Steve()

s.pickUp('wood')
s.pickUp('wood')
s.pickUp('dirt')
print(s.inv)
```

I will see that the list is empty. What is the mistake and why?

*Sorry for my bad english im Slavic*

Comment: `for i in self.inv:` - if your `self.inv` is empty then nothing in this loop will ever execute.

Comment: `self.inv[i] == self.inv[i] + amount` - I think you meant to use `=` not `==`.

Comment: Where is the call to `.append`? can it be reached if the list is empty?

Comment: Also, `for` iterates over the list's elements. `self.inv[i]` will raise a `TypeError`

Comment: You might want to check out `collections.Counter`, which can simplify your `pickUp` method to a single line.

Comment: @matszwecja and if used correctly to `O(1)` instead of `O(n)`

Answer (score 1):

Because "self. inv" is empty in the class definition, the program does not execute the for loop statement.
You can preset a value for the "self. inv" list.
There is an error in the line

```py
self. inv [i]==self. inv [i]+amount
```

If the str type is passed in, it cannot be added.

Comment: And you should use dict type to implement this class. It is not particularly appropriate to use list type.

Answer (score 1):

You for loop won't behave as expected, it will most of the times end up in the `else` case, appending the same item multiple times.

In your case, I'd ask in the `pick_up()` method:

```py
# use snake case naming convention
def pick_up(self, item):
    amount = 0
    if item in self.inv:
        amount +=1
    else:
        self.inv.append(item)
```

however, this leaves you with amount being 0 on each new call to `pick_up()`.

So in your case, I suggest to make `self.inv` a dictionary, then:

```py
def pick_up(self, item):
    if item in self.inv.keys():
        self.inv[item] += 1
    else:
        self.inv[item] = 0
```

if you make it a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) `self.inv = defaultdict(int)`, you don't need to worry about the `else` case:

```py
def pick_up(self, item):
    self.inv[item] += 1
```

Comment: The last implementation never add new items

Comment: it does, as `item` is used as key. if the key is not yet in the defaultdict, it adds the key and adds 1.

Comment: Well, it won't because the `if` is always `False.` If using `defaultdict(int)` you don't need the `if` at all. The entire function can simply be `self.inv[item] += 1`

Comment: Agree, you are right, thanks for pointing that out, @DeepSpace! Shame on me I didn't run the snippet locally :/ updated my answer!